# Download Specific Android Source Code

Tags: download, android-source

I would just like to know how to download specific version of Android Source Code. I have already tried the following command

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync
```

and I was able to download gingerbread 2.3.4. However, I would also like to download 2.3.3. Is there anyone who can tell me the proper command? Is there also a way to the download the source code without version files because I have no plans of changing the source code and uploading?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to download 2.3.3 by using the these commands:

```
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b android-2.3.3_r1
repo sync
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is there any other way to download this version of source code without git or repo ? since i have unreliable net connection and i need a way to download the code that can be resumed .. thanks in advance

Comment: @Ahmed Kotb, I am sorry but I haven't tried doing that yet. Do you mean downloading the source code via HTTP or FTP instead of git/repo? As of now, I don't know of other way but if find out how, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 14):

You could download the source from 
 http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1

Other versions are also available. You could search them in this site.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question has been answered, none of the answers work for me. It took me a while to figure this out, so I thought I would share the answer as it may save someone some pain.

To download the source code go to the github mirror, you can download a ZIP (see the left of the screenshot the "Download ZIP" button) and select the tag of the version you want. See this screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Btw here's the new github link https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base (they changed github profile from android to aosp-mirror)

Answer (score 3):

There is not the android-2.3.4_r1 tag in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest repository.

For example, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik repository has the android-2.3.4_r1 tag. You are able to see that tag on https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+refs.

To sum up, the android-2.3.4_r1 tag is tagged in a part of android repositories.

If you check the android-2.3.4_r1 tagging source code on dalvik, try this commands as below.

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync
cd dalvik
git checkout android-2.3.4_r1
```

Comment: Hi Wataru. Thank you for your answer. I would just like to confirm your answer. Does it mean that if I execute "git checkout android-2-3-3_r1" it will switch to 2.3.3 source code?

Comment: Yes, it does. However, that you can switch to 2.3.3 is limited to the project( dalvik, kernel... ) is tagged by "android-2.3.3_r1".